# Trying to change a variable in use to what the user inputs

Tags: python, variables, input

I have not found an answer that satisfies my needs or is simple enough for me to actually understand as I'm relatively new to python!

I have a variable labelled difficulty which asks the user to input a string to state whether they want easy medium or hard mode. Unfortunately I am unable to successfully have python check the input for the words used and give them what i want, i end up with "easy is not defined" or "medium is not defined" or "hard is not defined." Is there a way for me to get round this problem?  Here is a small section of my code which the problem is enclosed to:

```
difficulty=input("What difficulty do you wish to choose, easy,medium or hard?")
   if difficulty==easy:
        print("You have chosen the easy mode, your test will now begin")
        print("")

    elif difficulty==medium:
        print("You have chosen the medium mode, your test will now begin")

    else:
        print("You have chosen the hard mode or tried to be funny, your test 
        will now begin")
```

Comment: You have to compare the input to a string: `if difficulty == "easy":`

Comment: `difficulty == "easy"`. You need string literals here.

Comment: @Jan `raw_input` was removed from python with version 3.

Comment: Thank you Prune, I didn't notice that silly error on my behalf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, fix your indentation (if it is not a problem only in your example). Second, you need to put easy, medium, and hard in either single `'` or double `"` quotes:

```
difficulty=input("What difficulty do you wish to choose, easy,medium or hard?")
if difficulty=="easy":
    print("You have chosen the easy mode, your test will now begin")
    print("")

elif difficulty=="medium":
    print("You have chosen the medium mode, your test will now begin")

else:
    print("You have chosen the hard mode or tried to be funny, your test 
    will now begin")
```

If you don't put them in quotes, then you aren't comparing `difficulty` to the word easy, but rather to the variable called `easy`. This of course causes an error, since no such variable exists. The quotes however tell python to interpret easy as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a string from the user (`input` will return a string) then compare it to another string in this case `'easy'` or `'medium'`. [Here is a link to](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings) a google dev article talking about some of the basic things you can do to strings in python.

```
difficulty = input("What difficulty do you wish to choose, easy,medium or hard?")
if difficulty == 'easy':
    print("You have chosen the easy mode, your test will now begin")
    print("")

elif difficulty == 'medium':
    print("You have chosen the medium mode, your test will now begin")

else:
    print("You have chosen the hard mode or tried to be funny, your test will now begin")
```

When you put `easy` or `medium` in your code you are telling python that they are variables ([link to python variable tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types)) not strings. In this case you have not defined the `easy` variable yet ie: `easy = 'some data'`. Because you have not defined it python does not know what to do with `easy` it will throw an error.